# Composer development with local Dependencies

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm working on two connected PHP project at the same time (let's call them, kernel, api) and I'm using [composer](https://getcomposer.org) to manage dependecies.

Needless to say, `api` needs `kernel` to run but I cannot, at least during development phase, to upload on packagist every commit and then update the `api`'s dependencies.

Is there a way to, say to composer, while dev mode is enabled, take the dependence `kernel` from a local path?

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path ?

Comment: Thank you Jon Stirling, what about managing dependencies in production and development? Is it a good way to have to different composer? let's call composer_dev.json and composer.json? My idea is that, in dev mode you link to a local path, otherwise, you fetch the package (or the repo directly) and you save it in vendor/. What do you think about it?

Comment: Personally I would try not to get into the situation in the first place. Dev and prod should be as close as possible, if one it pulls dependencies from VCS, so should the other, if one pulls them from packigist, so should the other. That's simply my opinion.

Comment: That's right, the problem here is that I have two distinct cases:
 - once in production, kernel is up to date and, every time I deploy, I can pull from the repository the last version
 - in development instead, I need to link to the kernel through local path, not  by pulling from the repo. 

Am I explaining well the problem?